# JScrollPane не работает вертикальный скролл

Tags: html, css, jscrollpane

На странице есть `div` и со свойством `contentditable = true` и плагин `jScrollPane`. Проблема в том что горизонтальный скролл (который не нужен) работает, а вертикальный нет.

CSS:

```
#chat {
    width: 325px;
    height: 265px;

    overflow: hidden;
}
.chat_box{
    outline: none;
    border:  1px solid #b3b9c3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 325px;
    height: 260px;
}
.scroll{
    width: 325px;
    height: 260px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chat').jScrollPane();
});
```

HTML:

```
![<div class="scroll" id="chat">
    <div class="chat" >
        <div class="chat_box" contenteditable="true">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>]
```

[image]

На картинке видно - горизонтальный скролл работает, но он не нужен. А вертикальный скролл не работает совсем. Причем он должен быть такого же цвета как и горизонтальный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка кроется в задании для `#chat` свойства `overflow:hidden;`, нужно поменять значение этого свойства на `auto`. [Вот рабочий пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/LD1RPg3hbF6u4WPoBEB8?p=preview)